# Android Lint warning: "Redundant array creation for calling varargs method"

Tags: android, android-lint

I am getting the above Lint warning in my Android project for the `new Void[] {}` part of the following code:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showToast("Restarting NFC...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            disableNfcForegroundDispatch();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            enableNfcForegroundDispatch();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception e) {
        if (e == null) {
            showToast("...NFC restarted.");
        }
        else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not restart NFC!", e);
            showToast("Could not restart NFC: " + e);
        }
    }

}.execute(new Void[] {});
```

I am unable to replace the problematic `new Void[] {}` with `null`, so what is the correct solution?

Comment: Did you try it with no argument?

Comment: Yes, that's worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave the argument list empty:

```
.execute();
```